# different countries for shipping and billing in magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I want to have different number of countries to be present in shipping and billing  address in magento ?If I had countries from backend,it will show in both in  shipping and billing address dropdown,I don't want that,I want separate number of countries in both shipping and billing address field.How to do  that ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no in-built facility for doing this. You would probably have to overload / rewrite `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing` or `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping` to change the value returned by `getCountries`. This may be the only step required, although I suspect you will also have to overload a step in along the validation process.

Answer (score 1):

taken from - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59566/   --> works for me

```
in (path_to_magento)\app\design\frontend\default\my_skin_name)\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml

around line 103, remove or comment out this line: 
<?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('shipping') ?>

and replace with: 
<select name="shipping[country_id]" id="shipping:country_id" class="validate-select"        title="Country" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"> 
<option value=""> </option> 
<option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option> 
</select>
```

Or your own set of countries you explicitly want to show. As long as you have the valid 2 letter country abbreviation, Magento should take care of the rest on state/province selection automatically for you.